# WebClient.DownloadString() methods special character issue

Tags: asp.net

I have return ToBase64 string from WCF Service.
I called that method through WebClient (in .net) using downloadstring() method.
I get result but some special character are added (\,"\ ,/" etc) in result.(i.e Non Base64)

If I call method by creating WCF Client then it return correct string.
But in my application I need to call through WebClient.

What is the solution to get correct string(base64) ?